# Rails How do I sort a model without making it an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display some items from my database and I need to sort them alphabetically. This is the loop:

```
@foods.where(category: "#{Food::CATEGORIES[cat]}").find_each do |food|

..............

end
```

I tried setting default_scope:

```
default_scope { order(name: :asc) }
```

which did nothing and tried sorting them like this:

```
@foods = @foods.sort_by{|food| food.name }
```

after which I had caught an exception saying "can't use method 'where' on array'.

What can I do with it?

EDIT: @foods definition:

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_food, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorize, only: [:create, :delete]

  def index
    @foods = Food.all
    @food_categories = Food::CATEGORIES.keys.sort
    # @current_category ||= params(:category)

  end

....

end
```

EDIT: food categories here if it matters:

```
CATEGORIES = { "Dairy & Eggs" => "Dairy",
                "Meat & Fish" => "Animal",
                "Fruits & Vegetables" => "Plant",
                "Nuts, beans & legumes" => "Nuts",
                "Grains" => "Grains",
                "Drinks" => "Beverages",
                "Sweets & Candy" => "Sweets",
                "Oils & Fats" => "Oils",
                "Other" => "Other"
```

}

Comment: can you add to question `@foods` definition?

Comment: Two things, first if Food is a model in your app, then you can use Food.where(your condition/s).order(name: :asc), second the default_scope should work if you are applying it right, maybe you are trying to use it from the console and you have not restarted your console or reloaded it?

Comment: Added @foods definition

Comment: @waheedi no I was not trying ot use it from the console. And I tried order(name: :asc) and it didn't work :\

Comment: You left out your implementation of `Food::CATEGORIES`

Comment: @AlexanderDonets can you paste your model food, I think that's the one matters, and have you tried this? Food.where(your condition/s).order(name: :asc)

Answer (score 0):

You've got  "can't use method 'where' on array' because `Food.all` return array. Just use `@foods = Food.order(:name)`.

Comment: And it still doesn't sort it :|

Comment: Show your output log with raw generated sql queries. And are you using postgres or mysql?

Comment: what do you mean by "Show your output log with raw generated sql queries"?

MySQL